# Append barcode images to docx file using pybarcode ImageWriter and docx module

Tags: python

How can i reduce the image size which is generated by pybarcode ImageWriter, and also how can append multiple images to docx file with proper alignment?

I read about **dpi** option for ImageWriter but not getting how to use it.

```
import barcode
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
from docx import *

if __name__ == '__main__':        
    # Default set of relationshipships - these are the minimum components of a document
    ean = barcode.get_barcode('ean', '123456789102', writer=ImageWriter())
    ean.default_writer_options['module_height'] = 3.0
    ean.default_writer_options['module_width'] = 0.1
    filename = ean.save('bar_image')    

    relationships = relationshiplist()

    # Make a new document tree - this is the main part of a Word document
    document = newdocument()

    # This xpath location is where most interesting content lives 
    docbody = document.xpath('/w:document/w:body', namespaces=nsprefixes)[0]
    # Add an image
    relationships,picpara = picture(relationships, filename,'This is a test description')
    docbody.append(picpara)

    # Create our properties, contenttypes, and other support files
    coreprops = coreproperties(title='Python docx demo',subject='A practical example of making docx from Python',creator='Mike MacCana',keywords=['python','Office Open XML','Word'])
    appprops = appproperties()
    contenttypes = contenttypes()
    websettings = websettings()
    wordrelationships = wordrelationships(relationships)

    # Save our document
        savedocx(document,coreprops,appprops,contenttypes,websettings,wordrelationships,'sample_barcode.docx')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the barcode.writer **doesn't** give a parameter on the generated output image size, and you may ask [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) help. And the **proper alignment** is quite not accurate to code, but you may try using tables to make them in right place.

In PIL, you can resize the png image to (480,320)  by

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("barcode.png")
im.resize((480,320)).save("barcode_resized.png")
```

And for the docx file, some table example is [here](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx/blob/master/example-makedocument.py), you may need know what proper aliment is and then type the code.